# Capturing states between tags and href by xpath in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, lxml

Maybe needs some tricks.

Imagine I have the following file.html:

```
<ul class="test"><li>A: A</li><li>B: B</li><li>C: C</li><li>D: <a href="http://example.com" title="http://example.com" test3="_blank"><span><span>AAA</span><span class="test2">BBB</span><span>CCC</span></span></a></li><br></ul>
```

This is what I tried in python:

```
from lxml import html
f=open('/tmp/out.htm', 'r+')
lines=f.read()
tree=html.fromstring(lines)
print tree.xpath('//ul[@class="test"]/li/text()')
```

The output is:

```
['A: A', 'B: B', 'C: C', 'D: ']
```

But I want this result:

```
['A: A', 'B: B', 'C: C', 'D: http://example.com']
```

`D: http://example.com` is grabbed from `<a href="http://example.com"` part.

How can I do that by **xpath**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`text_content` method](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlMixin-class.html#text_content) which returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup:

```
...
>>> tree = html.fromstring(lines)
>>> [li.text_content() for li in tree.xpath('//ul[@class="test"]/li')]
['A: A', 'B: B', 'C: C', 'D: AAABBBCCC']
```

If you want to get `href` attribute:

```
>>> [li.text + ' '.join(li.xpath('a/@href'))
     for li in tree.xpath('//ul[@class="test"]/li')]
['A: A', 'B: B', 'C: C', 'D: http://example.com']

>>> [li.text + next(iter(li.xpath('a/@href')), '')
     for li in tree.xpath('//ul[@class="test"]/li')]
['A: A', 'B: B', 'C: C', 'D: http://example.com']
```

Comment: @MortezaLSC but your expected output seems different.

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Ah.. Do you want `href` attribute value, not the texts?

Comment: @MortezaLSC, how is `AAABBBCCC` a link?

Comment: When you join all between `spans` it would be link... Other answers to grab href is also welcome

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Try `[li.text + ' '.join(li.xpath('a/@href')) for li in tree.xpath('//ul[@class="test"]/li')]` or `[li.text + next(iter(li.xpath('a/@href')), '') for li in tree.xpath('//ul[@class="test"]/li')]`

Comment: @falsetru This is correct. thank you... You can put it in answer part.. +1

Comment: @MortezaLSC, I added them to the answer.